# Parsing a .pdb file in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a quick parser for .pdb files (they show protein structure). An example of a protein I am looking at is KRAS (common in cancer) and is here: http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/files/3GFT.pdb

If you scroll down far enough you will get to a line that looks like this:
ATOM      1  N   MET A   1      63.645  97.355  31.526  1.00 33.80           N

The first element "atom" means this relates to an actual atom in the protein. The 1 relates to a general count, N relates to the type of atom, "MET" is the name of the residue, "A" relates to the the type of chain, 1 (the second "1") is the atom count and then the next 3 numbers are the x-y-z positions in space.

What I need output is something like this (where the "1" below corresponds to the atom count, not the general count):
MET A 1 63.645  97.355  31.526

To make matters more complicated, sometimes the atom count (the second "1" in this case) is negative. In those cases I want to skip that line an continue until I hit a positive entry as those elements relate to the biochemistry needed to find the positions and not the actual protein. To make matters even worse, sometimes you get a line as such:

ATOM    139  CA AILE A  21      63.260 111.496  12.203  0.50 12.87           C
ATOM    140  CA BILE A  21      63.275 111.495  12.201  0.50 12.17           C

While they both refer to residue 21, the biochem isn't precise enough to get an exact position, so they give two options. Ideally, I would specify "1", "2" or whatever, but if I just take the first option that would be ok. Finally, for the type of atom ("N") in my original example, I only want to get those lines with a "CA".

I'm a newbie to python, and my training is in biostats so I was wondering what's the best way to do this? Do I parse this line by line with a for loop? Is there a way to do it faster in python? How do I handle the double entries for some atoms?

I realize it's a bit to ask, but some guidance would be a ton of help! I've programmed all the statistics bits in using R, but now I just need to get my files in the right format!

Thanks!

Comment: Is this related: http://code.google.com/p/pdb-tools/?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a long description. I am not sure I got all that correctly :-)
If the fields (for the lines start with ATOM) are fixed, 
you could use a split and some comaprisons.
I've used a hash to see if the entry is already seen to eliminate 
the duplicate as you wanted.
Hope this would give you a start,

```
visited = {}
for line in open('3GFT.pdb'):
    list = line.split()
    id = list[0]
    if id == 'ATOM':
        type = list[2]
        if type == 'CA':
            residue = list[3]
            type_of_chain = list[4]
            atom_count = int(list[5])
            position = list[6:8]
            if atom_count >= 0:
                if type_of_chain not in visited:
                    visited[type_of_chain] = 1
                    print residue,type_of_chain,atom_count,' '.join(position)
```

Will output,

```
MET A 1 62.935 97.579
GLY B 0 39.524 105.916
GLY C 0 67.295 110.376
MET D 1 59.311 124.106
GLY E 0 44.038 96.819
GLY F 0 44.187 123.590
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this! It wasn't quite what I needed but I was able to to piece together the correct result! Thank you!

Comment: Slight corrections:
1) list[6:8] should be list[6:9]
2) the final if block should be:
  if(atom_count >= 1):
     if atom_count not in visited and type_of_chain==chain_required:

Comment: Just a heads up that split() should not be used on PDB files since the data is based on the column position. 

`ATOM   5762  CA  LEU B3854      19.760...` and `ATOM   5762  CA  LEU B 3854      19.760...` would cause errors.

Answer (score 17):

I am mildly surprised that no one mentioned the [Bio.PDB](https://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.PDB-module.html) package from BioPython. Writing a PDB parser on your own is a rather serious case of unnecessarily reinventing, I mean reimplementing the wheel.

[BioPython](https://biopython.org) is a useful collection of packages for working with other kinds of biological data (e.g. protein or nucleic acid sequences) as well.

**Update**

I added a few functions I use for downloading and reading PDB files by way of example:

```
import os
import sys
import urllib.request

import Bio
import Bio.PDB
import Bio.SeqRecord

def download_read_pdb(pdbcode, datadir, keepfile=True):
    """
    Downloads a PDB file from the Internet and saves it in a data directory.
    Then it reads and returns the structure inside.
    :param pdbcode: The standard PDB ID e.g. '3ICB'
    :param datadir: The directory where the downloaded file will be saved
    :param keepfile: if False, then the downloaded file will be deleted (default: keep the downloaded file)
    :return: a Bio.PDB Structure object or None if something went wrong
    """
    pdbfilenm = download_pdb(pdbcode, datadir)
    if pdbfilenm is None:
        return None
    struct = read_pdb(pdbcode, pdbfilenm)
    if not keepfile:
        os.remove(pdbfilenm)
    return struct
        
def download_pdb(pdbcode, datadir, downloadurl="http://files.rcsb.org/download/"):
    """
    Downloads a PDB file from the Internet and saves it in a data directory.
    :param pdbcode: The standard PDB ID e.g. '3ICB' or '3icb'
    :param datadir: The directory where the downloaded file will be saved
    :param downloadurl: The base PDB download URL, cf.
        `https://www.rcsb.org/pages/download/http#structures` for details
        Note that the unencrypted HTTP protocol is used by default
        to avoid spurious OpenSSL errors...
    :return: the full path to the downloaded PDB file or None if something went wrong
    """
    pdbfn = pdbcode + ".pdb"
    url = downloadurl + pdbfn
    outfnm = os.path.join(datadir, pdbfn)
    try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, outfnm)
        return outfnm
    except Exception as err:
        # all sorts of things could have gone wrong...
        print(str(err), file=sys.stderr)
        return None

def read_pdb(pdbcode, pdbfilenm):
    """
    Read a PDB structure from a file.
    :param pdbcode: A PDB ID string
    :param pdbfilenm: The PDB file
    :return: a Bio.PDB.Structure object or None if something went wrong
    """
    try:
        pdbparser = Bio.PDB.PDBParser(QUIET=True)   # suppress PDBConstructionWarning
        struct = pdbparser.get_structure(pdbcode, pdbfilenm)
        return struct
    except Exception as err:
        print(str(err), file=sys.stderr)
        return None 

def extract_seqrecords(pdbcode, struct):
    """
    Extracts the sequence records from a Bio.PDB structure.
    :param pdbcode: the PDB ID of the structure, needed to add a sequence ID to the result
    :param struct: a Bio.PDB.Structure object
    :return: a list of Bio.SeqRecord objects
    """
    ppb = Bio.PDB.PPBuilder()
    seqrecords = []
    for i, chain in enumerate(struct.get_chains()):
        # extract and store sequences as list of SeqRecord objects
        pps = ppb.build_peptides(chain)    # polypeptides
        seq = pps[0].get_sequence() # just take the first, hope there's no chain break
        seqid = pdbcode + chain.id
        seqrec = Bio.SeqRecord.SeqRecord(seq, id=seqid, 
            description="Sequence #{}, {}".format(i+1, seqid))
        seqrecords.append(seqrec)
    return seqrecords

def get_calphas(struct):
    """
    Extracts the C-alpha atoms from a PDB structure.
    :param struct: A Bio.PDB.Structure object.
    :return: A list of Bio.PDB.Atom objects representing the C-alpha atoms in `struct`.
    """
    calphas = [ atom for atom in struct.get_atoms() if atom.get_fullname() == " CA " ]
    return calphas
```

I am aware that this was an old question but maybe someone still finds this pointer helpful.

Comment: Is Bio.PDB crossplatform? Or it's yet another wrapper for DIA SDK?

Comment: It's written in Python AFAIK, so it's exactly as cross-platform as Python itself.

Comment: I would really appreciate a 5-10 liner of 'how to load using BioPDB', it's documentation is deeply nested and expects one to guess where to look for an example

Comment: @Alleo I added some code examples to my answer as requested.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like a library to parse PDB files already exists.  Check out:

http://prody.csb.pitt.edu/

Briefly looking through the tutorials, it seems like this is what you're talking about no?

http://www.csb.pitt.edu/prody/tutorial.html#atomic-data

Comment: It seems like with windows 7 x64, the registry is a bit different so the installer is complaining. Thanks for pointing me to this, I will take a look a bit later.

Comment: This is outdated as resource is removed.

Comment: This answer should be the preferred one as the ProDy parser is 2x faster than BioPython (even though they are both in python). Here is the new link: http://prody.csb.pitt.edu/

Answer (score 7):

For large `pdb` files with a lot of atoms, there is no blank left between fields, so you cannot use the `split` command. Instead, you can use the Protein Data Bank format definition to parse the `pdb` file:

```
with open('min.pdb') as pdbfile:
    for line in pdbfile:
        if line[:4] == 'ATOM' or line[:6] == "HETATM":
            print line
            # Split the line
            splitted_line = [line[:6], line[6:11], line[12:16], line[17:20], line[21], line[22:26], line[30:38], line[38:46], line[46:54]]
            print splitted_line
            # To format again the pdb file with the fields extracted
            print "%-6s%5s %4s %3s %s%4s    %8s%8s%8s\n"%tuple(splitted_line)
```

Below is a sample output:

```
# Original line:
HETATM10000  O   HOH B3257       2.509  40.006  -4.097  1.00  0.00           O

# Fields extracted:
['HETATM', '10000', ' O  ', 'HOH', 'B', '3257', '   2.509', '  40.006', '  -4.097']

# Reformatted line:
HETATM10000  O   HOH B3257       2.509  40.006  -4.097
```